Can't connect fastapi app on ec2 with RDS postgres
my problem is that I can't connect my fastapi app which is deployed in ec2 using docker. However, my app in local can connect successfully. The problem said : **Could not parse SQLAlchemy URL from string. **
I've already check the env in ec2 and make sure that I've put correct variables.
Could you help me to solve this
Many thanks
This is my config.py:
enter image description hereconfig.py
The error when i ran docker logs fastapi_container:
enter image description here
Expect should connect successfully to ec2
